# Very basic PDO method using bindParam()

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a similiar class with a lot of methods, but `getData()` only returns the value of the `$column` parameter.

```
private $db;

function __construct()
{
    $this->db = new PDO('sqlite:\db');
}

public function getData($rowid, $column)
{
    $st = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ? FROM tbl WHERE rowid=?');
    $st->bindParam(1, $column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindParam(2, $rowid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($st->execute())
        return $st->fetchColumn();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Every other parts of the class and the left out half of `getData()` works. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindParam` is used to bind parameters, not identifiers. The value you bind there will be expanded as:

```
SELECT 'some_value' FROM tbl WHERE rowid='some_other_value';
```

...therefore equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'some_value';
```

You should only use parameters for *actual parameters*:

```
$this->db->prepare('SELECT '.$column.' FROM tbl WHERE rowid=?');
```

If your column is user-supplied and you want to escape it, use the proper escaping function. In this case, it's [`SQLite3::escapeString()`](http://php.net/sqlite3.escapeString):

```
$column = SQLite3::escapeString($column);
$this->db->prepare('SELECT '.$column.' FROM tbl WHERE rowid=?');
```

If the column is not user-supplied, you don't really have to escape it.

Comment: @erenon: Possibly, but not necessarily. There are use cases where the user supplying the column name is a better design choice than maintaining a list of columns in the code. It's rare, but it may happen. Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

identifier is not a string.
you can't bind identifiers.
you have to whitelist them instead.

or - better - design your application proper way that will require no dynamical fieldname at all.

Comment: That is assuming `$column` is user-supplied, which may not even be the case. There is no way to tell with the actual code.

Comment: @netcoder It is not. This class supposed to be some kind of more specific interface between PDO and the application logic. Only `$rowid` is user-supplied, and I properly escape it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I only use this application to try out things, but what's the problem with having such a universal method?

Comment: @Gergő what's the point in "proper escaping" binded variable? What's the problem I could tell if I'd know the purpose.

Comment: @YourCommonSense "Escaping" was the wrong word, `$rowid` is supplied by the query string, and its validiated as an integer. In such cases should I just pass the parameters to `execute()`? And for single calls is it more reasonable to use `query()` and `exec()`? And finally is it a bad pratice in itself to have a method with _column_ as a parameter, or briefly what should I pay attention to? Thank you in advance!